# creating class made of subclasses from other files

Tags: python, file, class, oop

I am building a simple system which will have the central `university` class composed of the following classes:

```
  address
  person
  student
  professor
  course
  enrol
```

and these are all located in .py files in the same directory. I want to turn these classes into a single class (`university`). Should I simply have the university.py file be:

```
from address import address
from person import person 
from student import student 
from professor import professor 
from course import course 
from enrol import enrol
```

or should I create a university class (and if so, how should I do so?).

Comment: Can you include some more code so your intentions and progress can be more easily understood?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you need a `university` class, so you should create one and put it in `university.py` if you like. But, in order to implement such a class I can see you having to eventually have all those imports at the top of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can have one module for each class, it is not that usual in Python, and as you already know it requires imports for almost every class you use.

It is much more common for a Python module to have several related classes inside.

Then, if some of these classes become more complex, requiring themselves more related classes that essentially only matter to themselves and their inner work, they become candidates for extraction into their own modules.